# Applying BCJR equalization for LDPC encoded information

Tags: convolution, channelcoding, ecc

I want to apply [BCJR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BCJR_algorithm) decoder for LDPC encoded information.
How can I change the BCJR originally for convolutional codes for this purpose?

Comment: There's BCJR variants for LDPC. Since we don't know which BCJR implementation / algorithm you're using, we really can't tell you what to adapt. Chances are, this doesn't make much sense, because you might not want to do the same things for giant sparse matrices numerically as you do for some a-few-states-transition based convolutional code.

Comment: @MarcusMüller thanks. I look for a suitable BCJR implementation for this case, do you know something?

Comment: Can you try to give us *any* information in what you're looking for in an implementation? (what should it run on, what's the size of your LDPCs, what are the rates you need to achieve, are you bound to a programming language or hardware design language? Are we talking hardware or software?)

Comment: I'll be honest, though: Albeit I remember a couple of papers on these, I don't know whether you can *get* these implementations, or whether they are adaptable to your specific use case. If in doubt, I'm afraid I'll have to admit that I can just refer you to a search on google scholar.

Comment: @MarcusMüller thanks for your replies.I want to use the following bcjr implementation in this link (called there turbo decoding:
https://github.com/veeresht/CommPy/blob/master/commpy/channelcoding/turbo.py
my LDPC code has the rate of 3/4. Do you know what I should do?